# Permissions error

Tags: themes, permissions

I am completely new to WordPress. I just installed it and wanted to change the theme of my website and I get following error:

```
Installing Theme: Klasik 0.7.5

Downloading install package from https://wordpress.org/themes/download/klasik.0.7.5.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory.
```

I really don't know what to do from that point. My permissions are ubuntu www-data ( I am running this on lxc ). Please, please tell me what I have to do!! I tried to get wp working on Windows and everything worked. Now on Linux its just not working and I could destroy my monitor at the moment.... -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more server config question than WordPress.

Make sure the www-data group has write permissions in the directory you're running WordPress from. Assuming it's in /var/www/ then `sudo chmod -R g+rwxs /var/www/` should do the trick.

Comment: Note that server configuration as related to WordPress _is_ considered in scope here.